# Receiving data function stalls when requesting large chunk of data

Tags: c, sockets, recv, locked

I'm creating a mini web server in C.

The following function is supposed to read in data from the client computer.

The objective is to read the second piece of data after the first space. Each piece of incoming data is space separated.

For example, if the incoming data is:

GET /123/456

then I'd expect /123/456.

If the incoming data is:

GET /123/456 789

then I'd still expect /123/456.

This relevant fragment is from an external function that sets up a 10 KB buffer and calls the problematic function:

```
//nsock is a valid socket handle from an accept() call.
printf("CLIENT CONNECTION!\n");
char req[10000];long reqsz=10000;
getreq(req,&reqsz,nsock);
printf("Received %d bytes\n",reqsz);
printf("Data: %s\n",req);
```

"CLIENT CONNECTION!" appears on the screen, but "Received" does not appear if bufsize inside the function is a high value. If I set it to a low value like 16, or 100, then everything is displayed correctly. Why do large numbers like 5000 not work?

This is the problematic function:

```
//getreq params in:   req=external buffer for data
//            reqsz=size of external buffer. I set 10000
//            nsock=valid socket pointer from accept()
//
//getreq params out:  reqsz=actual size of data returned
    //                    req=actual data
//
void getreq(char* req,unsigned long *reqsz,long nsock){
    //bufsize=how many bytes to read at once. High values like 5000 cause a stall.
    //buffer=buffer of data from recv call
    const unsigned long ibs=*reqsz,bufsize=5000;
    char buffer[ibs],*rp=req;
    //spacect=# of spaces in data read
    //szct=iterator variable
    //mysz=total length of returned data
    //bufct=buffer counter to prevent segfault
    //recvsz=data size returned from recv or
    //       forced -2 if buffer hits capacity
    //       or 2nd space in returned data is found
    unsigned long spacect=0,szct=0,mysz=0,bufct=0;
    long recvsz=1;char *p=buffer;
    //
    //Expected data: GET /whatever HTTP/x.x but we
    //               want /whatever
    //
    //loop until 2nd space is found or 
    //ibs bytes of data have been processed
    while (recvsz > 0 && bufct < ibs){
        recvsz=recv(nsock, p, bufsize, 0);
        if (recvsz < 1){break;}
        for (szct=1;szct<=recvsz;szct++){
            if (*p==' '){spacect++;if (spacect > 2){spacect=2;recvsz=-2;break;}}
            if (spacect==1 && *p != ' '){mysz++;if (mysz <= *reqsz){*rp++=*p;}}
            p++;bufct++;if (bufct > ibs){recvsz=-2;break;}
        }
    }
    // Process rest of data to try to avoid client errors
    while (recvsz == -2){
        recvsz=recv(nsock, buffer, bufsize, 0);
    }
    *reqsz=mysz;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your mini web server does not have enough stack space for `char req[10000];` and the dependent (same size) `buffer[ibs]`.

Comment: Is there enough data to satisfy the recv? Are appropriate parameters set on the socket to get recv to return if there's some data avail, but not the full amount requested?

Comment: @WeatherVane It would be odd to have a problem with stack space in a user process, particularly with such a small (1K) allocation involved. That sort of thing usually only affects code in the kernel - at least in general purpose OS'es.

Comment: You cannot rely on `recv()` reading `bufsize` bytes. Use `recvsz` to determine the amount of bytes read. It may very well vary from 1 to `bufsize`.

Comment: @ArlieStephens I wondered if it is embedded code with small resources. The 2 arrays need 20k bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane my bad on the space computation. And I just assumed general purpose OS, since there was no indication of anything different, and it was using socket calls. Hopefully the OP will let us know.

Comment: In any case, having a variable length array (VLA) who's size depends on input is a *very bad* idea. This is a very easily attackable.

Comment: I wonder if Arlie is right. Maybe recv is meant to stall until the client data is of at least bufsize total. I'm doing this in unix.

Comment: @Mike No, recv() is not meant to "stall". It can return whenever there is even one byte of data, or an error, to return.